# Отцентрировать блок внутри блока

Tags: html, css

Нужно помощь в отцентрировании `cont2` относительно `cont1`. Когда длина `cont1` больше, чем `cont2`, то все отлично. Но если `cont1` поставить длину `100px`, то `cont2` уже будет не по центру относительно `cont1`, а от края.

Вот что я хочу получить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.cont1 {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.cont2 {
    width: 200px; 
    height: 200px;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

```html
<div class="cont1">
    <div class="cont2">Test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: если  cont1 поставить длину 100px, то cont2 уже будет не по центру относительно cont1, а от края --- так у вас cont1 width: 200px; Может быть задать ширины в %

Comment: У двух блоков фиксированная длина. Если `cont2` длиннее, чем `cont1`, то края `cont2` должны выходить за границы `cont1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если такой вариант ???

```css
.wrapp {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cont1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 250px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

.cont2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapp">
  <div class="cont1">
    <div class="cont2">Test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Тогда `cont1` будет растягиваться до длины `cont2`

Comment: Добавил пример, не растягивается, посмотрите. Сделал специально cont1 высоту чуть больше для наглядности

Comment: Но `cont2` все равно не в центре  `cont1`. Часть блока  `cont2` должна была уйти за левый край.

Comment: Как cont2 может быть в центре, если у него ширина 200, а у cont1 ширина 100 ?

Comment: Ну вот я и хочу того добиться, если длина cont1 меньше, чем у cont2, то часть блока cont2 как бы уходит за левый край.

Comment: мне кажется нашел решение, сейчас выложу

Comment: Добавил, смотрите, как такой вариант?

Comment: Еще чучуть добавил своего. Получилось то, что хотел. Большое спасибо.

Comment: Рад был помочь ))

Answer (score 0):

Старый добрый способ позиционирования по центру с использованием `position: absolute` и `transform`.

```css
.cont1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px blue;
}

.cont2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/* for demo */
body {display: flex; min-height: 100vh; margin: 0; overflow: hidden;}
.cont2 {max-width: 100vw; max-height: 100vh; overflow: hidden; resize: both;}
```

```html
<div class="cont1">
  Test
  <div class="cont2"></div>
</div>
```

Так же добавил возможность ресайзить блок с красной обводкой, чтобы продемонстрировать, что при разных размерах блока с красной обводкой, будет всегда центрироваться относительно блока с синей обводкой.